# Django как называть изображения pk пользователя

Tags: python, django

У меня есть форма, на основе класса **UpdateView**:

```
class UserUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['name', 'text', 'tel', 'adress', 'img', 'name_link_1',
        'link_1','name_link_2', 'link_2','name_link_3', 'link_3',
        'name_link_4', 'link_4','name_link_5', 'link_5',]
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if not self.request.user.pk == self.object.pk:
            return redirect('login')
        return context
```

В форме всего одно изображение, которое связанно с одним конкретным пользователем. Я хочу вместо названия загружаемого изображения давать ему название по **pk** пользователя. Вопрос в том, как мне это сделать?

models.py:

```
img = models.ImageField('Ваша аватарка', upload_to='images/', blank=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полагаю это может помочь:

```
def upload_as_pk(instance, filename: str):
    """Загружает файл в новую директрорию
    """
    instance_folder = type(instance).__name__.lower()  # Папка, где хранить изображения
    filename_format = filename.split('.')[-1]  # Формат файла, извлекаете любым удобным способом
    return f'{instance_folder}/{instance.pk}.{filename_format}'
```

В модели указываете эту функцию в `upload_to`

```
img = models.ImageField('Ваша аватарка', upload_to=upload_as_pk, blank=True)
```

PS: Ответ не проверял, но должен работать

Comment: Да, только что нашёл подобное, и это работает для меня)

Comment: Раз уж, Вы ответили. Можно ещё один глупый вопрос? Как лучше вывести их в шаблоне, если они хранятся в media. Что-то типо: `{{ img.url }}, выдает подобный путь: /media/folder/img.png но django не находит её

Comment: На боевом сервере статика и медиа отдаются средствами сервера, для разработки можно прописать в `urls.py` как тут https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development , но для медиа. А вообще это должно было быть оформлено отдельным вопросом

Comment: > А вообще это должно быть отдельным вопросом. Соглашусь, но в данном случае он слишком частный чтобы быть кому-то полезным, всё равно спасибо